# Setting multi-fingers in MOSFET in series configuration in Cadence Virtuoso schematic

Tags: mosfet, schematics, cmos, cadence, virtuoso

I am trying to figure out to set multi-fingers (nf = 3) for MOSFET (both P-MOS and N-MOS.)

I know I can increase the length directly. As connecting MOSFETs in series increases length, can I somehow configure the finger properties (nf > 1) of the MOSFET in such a way that S/D of each finger connects in series? I am asking to do it in the schematic, not in layout yet.

I am using Cadence Virtuoso and 22nm technology.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. In a FET with multiple fingers, these are all equivalent to parallel devices.